# Getting pretty string of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift

is there any way to get a pretty string of a dictionary?

from this kind of mess:

```
[AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 394, AnyHashable("Via"): 1.1 varnish, AnyHashable("Date"): Sun, 07 May 2017 10:01:14 GMT]
```

to this:

```
{
  "Content-Length": 394,
  "Via": "1.1 varnish",
  "Date": "Sun, 07 May 2017 10:01:14 GMT"
}
```

except `for` loop.

I know `dump()`.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @vadian like a formatted json dictionary with indentations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension.

If you print a Swift dictionary casted to `NSDictionary` you get the Foundation appearance.

```
extension Dictionary {

    func dump()
    {
        print(self as NSDictionary)
    }
}

let dict : [AnyHashable : Any] = [AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 394, AnyHashable("Via"): "1.1 varnish", AnyHashable("Date"): "Sun, 07 May 2017 10:01:14 GMT"]
dict.dump()
```

Basically you cannot output the JSON appearance without converting the dictionary to JSON.